# hive ql - posexplode with more than 2 columns

Tags: hiveql, explode

Have 3 arrays:
[21,31,41], [121,131,141], [1021,1031,1041]

Wanted to explode as:
21, 121, 1021
31, 131, 1031
41, 141, 1041

I have written like this:
select key1, key2, key3 from
lateral view posexplode(col_name_1) key1 as q1, key1
lateral view posexplode(col_name_2) key2 as q2, key2
lateral view posexplode(col_name_3) key3 as q3, key3

where q1=q2 and q1=q3;

Gets an exception as:
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: Why do you need posexplode? `select array1[0], array2[0], array3[0], array1[1], array2[1], array3[1] and so on`

Comment: Did you inspect the YARN logs for that job to know **why** it returned an error code?